# TensorFlow example for text classification - how to evaluate your own text?

Tags: text, tensorflow, text-classification

Does any one have full steps  and example for TensorFlow example for passing in your own text files and getting them evaluated against the existing model that comes with examples - using `train.py` as documented?

Also, if I wanted to train on different input set of say 1000 text files of my own samples, and then use that model for new text files? I know there is documentation but is terse for someone who is not familiar with text classification process.

I was able to run image example against my own images as that was only requiring to swap out one image `.jpg` file name for myh new image file, but for text it seems to be more involved.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the [Vector representation of words model?](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) Because that one just downloads and unzips a giant text file, so you can just replace `text8.zip` with a different zipfile name, or with plain text, skip the beginning and use `words = open('myfile.txt').read().split()`.

Comment: I started from this link: https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf - run train.py fine, now I wanted to provide my text to run the model against it. But I could not tie it to the code in train.py - where the input file is, etc.

Comment: .. but any other starting point for text classification as described above would be fine.

Comment: `train.py` calls another function `data_helpers.load_data()` so you have to look in `data_helpers.py`. The function `load_data_and_labels()` shows where the files are. You need one file for 'positive' results and one file for 'negative.'  -- By the way, welcome to Stackoverflow! Next time, it's better to post questions like this, about how to run someone's code, in the blogger's comments section and to only use SO for questions about general coding concepts or public libraries...things the whole community would care about.

Comment: Try this link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/skflow

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/skflow/text_classification.py

You can set the flag test_with_fake_data to use the fake data in text_train.csv (training samples) and text_test.csv (testing samples) [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/data/). Next, you can modify these two files to include whatever data you'd like to have. You will need to do some preprocessing if your existing text files are in a different format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the vocabulary file saved during training and process your new text with that. See the eval.py file [here](https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf)

Change the data parameters with your input text and proceed.